# Replace matching values in array with message

Tags: php, arrays, replace

An *example* of what my validator (in my controller) is returning is the following array with error codes:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Required
            [1] => Alpha
            [2] => NoSpace
        )

    [terms] => Array
        (
            [0] => Required
        )
)
```

And in my View (UI logic) I want to replace every matching error code with sentence in this array:

```
$messages = array(
    'name' => array(
        'Required' => 'You did not enter your first name.',
        'MaxChars' => 'Your first name cannot be longer then 35 characters.',
        'Alpha'    => 'Your first name must contain only alpha characters.'
    ),
    'terms' => array(
        'Required' => 'You must agree to our policies.'
    )
);
```

And if there is no match, I want to just keep the current value it already has.

So in this case, NoSpace error code would stay NoSpace (because no match), but for the other error codes they would be replaced with the corresponding message.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
<?php

foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
   for ($i=0, $c = count($v); $i<$c; ++$i) {
      if (isset($messages[$k][$v[$i]])) {
           $arr[$k][$i] = $messages[$k][$v[$i]];
      }
   }
}
```